# PhpStorm problem in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, java, php, ide

I have a problem starting [PhpStorm 5](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) on Ubuntu 12.04, it shows the following errors stack:
I installed Ubuntu just now, so its a fresh copy, changed only ubuntu 2d when logged in, installed Java from Oracle, so its available for sure.
Can somebody help, will really appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

```
vadim@vadim-MS-7309:~$ '/home/vadim/PhpStorm-121.390/bin/phpstorm.sh'
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/vadim/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1846)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1648)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1670)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.updateFrameClass(AppUIUtil.java:81)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:46)
    ... 6 more
ERROR: Error while accessing com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start with arguments: []
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/vadim/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1846)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1648)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1670)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.updateFrameClass(AppUIUtil.java:81)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:46)
    ... 6 more
ERROR: Error while accessing com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start with arguments: []
java.lang.AssertionError: Error while accessing com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start with arguments: []
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.DefaultLogger.error(DefaultLogger.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:65)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Exception: java.lang.AssertionError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Idea Main Thread"
```

EDIT: The problem is that OS should be the same as PhpStorm, i had 64 OS and 32 PhpStorm.
Problem solved thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [his discussion in Jetbrain's youTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15571). The Ubuntu and the Java version should be both either 32Bit or 64Bit. If they differ the above error will occur. So make sure that you use the same flavours.